# Do delisted games on Steam count as perfected games if I would 100% them now?

Tags: steam, achievements

I have *No Time To Explain Remastered* and the delisted original version *No Time To Explain* in my library. The original is delisted from Steam Store, but I can still download and install it. Would this game count to the amount of perfected games for my profile?

Comment: Just out of interest, do you gain anything from perfected games? Or is it purely cosmetic?

Comment: @MaxD completionism!

Comment: I get +1. But I'm not sure yet if I will go for the 100% since I already did the Remastered version. It's some kind of "look I'm good at games and know indie games that good that I also have the classic version in my library and beaten" flexing showoff and the game is also fun :)

Answer (score 45):

**Yes.**

I completed the original version of Skyrim on Steam **after** it was delisted. The Perfect Games count went up by one.

Update: Found a way to prove it :).

[This post](https://steamcommunity.com/app/489830/discussions/0/2949168687313009016/) makes clear Skyrim was already delisted at 16th March 2018. I got my last achievement on 25th of May 2019.

[image: Last Oldrim achievement]

[Here](https://steamcommunity.com/id/Mixxiphoid/games/?tab=perfect) is the proof that it counts as Perfect Game
[image: Perfect games list of my Steam profile]

Answer (score 26):

**Yes**.

I have 100% in [Dark Souls: Prepare to Die edition](https://store.steampowered.com/agecheck/app/211420/), which is no longer available to purchase because of Remastered version.

However, it's still counted as one of my perfect games:

[image]

Comment: Did you you 100% it before it was delisted, or after?

Comment: @muru before delisting

Answer (score 4):

If a game was published with achievements on Steam, the tracking of those achievements will keep working regardless of the status of the game in the store: either delisted, superseded, or similar (I'd dare to say that this is true even if the publisher gets banned). As long as the game is in your library and had defined achievements at time of purchase/redemption/activation, it will work. Same for the community hub for the title. A game may not exist in the storefront anymore, but the elements of the community hub will keep being available unless there is a violation of the community guidelines (and consequent admonishing) by the developers/maintainers of the game.